# Typescript - Is there a difference between JSON.parse and typecasting, VS importing and typecasting?

Tags: typescript

What's the difference between:

**app.ts**

```
const data = [{
    startTs: '1',
    endTs: '2020-10-16T14:00:52.224Z',
    averageCount: 3.504,
    entrances: 0
},
{
    startTs: '1',
    endTs: '2020-10-16T14:00:52.224Z',
    averageCount: 3.504,
    entrances: 0
}];

const hr: HistoricalRecord[] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(j)) as HistoricalRecord[];
```

vs

**dataExx.json**

```
[
{
    startTs: '1',
    endTs: '2020-10-16T14:00:52.224Z',
    averageCount: 3.504,
    entrances: 0
},
{
    startTs: '1',
    endTs: '2020-10-16T14:00:52.224Z',
    averageCount: 3.504,
    entrances: 0
}
]
```

**app.ts**

```
import jsondata from '../../testData/dataExx.json';

const hr: HistoricalRecord[] = jsondata as HistoricalRecord[];
```

If you could try to answer the following, verbatim:

1. From what I can tell, JSON.parse results in "any" (first example) which is why you cast it as HistoricalRecord[], but what "type" is it when I just import the json instead? (example 2)
2. In this example, HistoricalRecord is a CLASS defined in another file.. would it matter if it were an interface?
3. Am I right in saying that Typescript offers no immediate type-safety when it comes to JSON ingesting - regardless of whether something is transformed to a class or an interface?

I'm aware these are really tedious questions, asked by a moron. But if you could answer those and even help me out with a general rundown of things I'd really appreciate it.

--

Edit:

Thanks for the help! :)

For reference, this is what HistoricalRecord.ts looks like:

**HistoricalRecord.ts**

```
export class HistoricalRecord {
    startTs: string;
    endTs: string;
    averageCount: number;
    entrances: number;

    constructor(startTs: string, endTs: string, averageCount: number, entrances: number) {
        this.startTs = startTs;
        this.endTs = endTs;
        this.averageCount = averageCount;
        this.entrances = entrances;
    }
}
```

I noticed that if I changed the JSON file's second entry's "averageCount" to a string like so:

**dataExx.json**

```
[
{
    startTs: '1',
    endTs: '2020-10-16T14:00:52.224Z',
    averageCount: 3.504,
    entrances: 0
},
{
    startTs: '1',
    endTs: '2020-10-16T14:00:52.224Z',
    averageCount: **"3.504"**,
    entrances: 0
}
]
```

Then the following would pass as TRUE:

**app.ts**

```
import jsondata from '../../testData/dataExx.json';

const hr: HistoricalRecord[] = jsondata as HistoricalRecord[];

console.log(typeof hr[1].averageCount === 'string') // TRUE
```

4. But you had said that it was strongly typed, so why isn't the compiler freaking out?
5. I noticed that if the JSON file was just ONE entry, and averageCount was a string, it would complain when I try to cast "as HistoricalRecord", but this mix of value types doesn't seem to be a problem when it's an array. What's going on here?

Sorry to be a nuisance

Answer (score 0):

In order to import JSON directly you have to tun on the `resolveJsonModule` compiler option. [(See docs)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#resolveJsonModule).

When it's off (the default) you can't use `import` with `.json` files at all.

When it's on you get strongly typed imports as if it was a JS file.

So Im going to assume you have that compiler flag turned on for the rest of this answer.

---

> 1. From what I can tell, JSON.parse results in "any" (first example) which is why you cast it as HistoricalRecord[], but what "type" is it when I just import the json instead? (example 2)

The type is:

```
{
    startTs: string;
    endTs: string;
    averageCount: number;
    entrances: number;
}[]
```

---

> 2. In this example, HistoricalRecord is a CLASS defined in another file.. would it matter if it were an interface?

No. A class used as a type is just a type that corresponds to the type of instances of that class.

Though classes usually have methods, and methods/functions cannot be serialized to JSON at all. So watch out for that.

---

> 3. Am I right in saying that Typescript offers no immediate type-safety when it comes to JSON ingesting - regardless of whether something is transformed to a class or an interface?

Incorrect. If you have `resolveJsonModule` enabled, then you get a very rich type that is pretty close to what you would get if you did `const data = { ... } as const`.

---

> 5. I noticed that if the JSON file was just ONE entry, and averageCount was a string, it would complain when I try to cast "as HistoricalRecord", but this mix of value types doesn't seem to be a problem when it's an array. What's going on here?

Type assertions with `as` are not fully type safe. For instance:

```
const foo: number | string = 123
const bar = foo as string // bar is typed as string, but contains a number
```

You use `as` when you know better than the type system could know, and that means you could know wrong. But for `as` to work, Typescript enforces that the value *could be* the cast type. Which means this will not work:

```
const bad = 123 as boolean // error
```

Typescript knows that it's impossible for a number to be a boolean, so it provides a type error.

Given that check out these scenarios:

```
import data from './data.json' // [{ val: 123 }, { val: 456 }]
type MyJsonType = typeof data // { val: number }[]
const castData = data as { val: number }[] // fine
```

This works because the type assertion `as { val: number }` is asserting a type that value could be.

```
import data from './data.json' // [{ val: 123 }, { val: 'abc' }]
type MyJsonType = typeof data // { val: number | string }[]
const castData = data as { val: number }[] // fine
```

This also works because the type assertion `as { val: number }` is asserting a type that value could be. But it's wrong, because `as` is not type safe.

```
import data from './data.json' // [{ val: 'abc' }, { val: 'abc' }]
type MyJsonType = typeof data // { val: string }[]
const castData = data as { val: number }[] // error
```

This one is a type error because `string` can never be a number, so Typescript assumes this `as` is certainly wrong.

But you don't need to use `as`, since the inferred type from the JSON file already conforms to the interface of your class. (as long as it has no methods, and the same fields)

```
const record: HistoricalRecord = myJsonData[0] // fine
record.averageCount // number
```

---

Checkout this sandbox where I import a json file. You can hover over the `MyJsonType` and see what it is. (Though I did notice that after you change the json file you have to refresh the page to get an updated type, so keep that in mind)

[See Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-fog-qj6ugd?file=/src/index.ts)

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer Alex, I've edited my original post to ask one further question (if you don't mind helping me)

Comment: See my edit, I misread the type inferred by the compiler, and added an answer to #5.

Comment: "4. But you had said that it was strongly typed, so why isn't the compiler freaking out?" WHy would the compiler "freak out"? `typeof true === 'number'` is perfectly valid typescript that evaluates to `false`.

Comment: I think you're missing brackets on `as { val: number }`? There's noooo way that TS would allow a cast from an array type to the type of its elements.